# JSON push to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

Trying to handle data collected via JSON.
Objects are received, but unable to convert to array to use with chart.js

```
var highscore = [];
$.getJSON('myurl',function(result){
  $.each(result, function(i, field){
    highscore.push(field.score);
    highscore.push(100):
  });
});
```

None of the two pushes to array is working, but I'm lost trying to figure out why that is.

Comment: It may help you to use console.log() and a debugger every now and then to verify your data and syntax; I see 1 syntax error right off the bat.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: How should i show the result?

Comment: @EvanBechtol: Replaced colon with semicolon didn't fixe the problem. No content being pushed to the highscore array.

Comment: console.log( highscore ) just displayes [].

Comment: Try logging your results and make sure they are what you expect, instead of high score

Comment: The object is displayed as expected. It still doesn't explain why highscore.push(100) doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by storing the object values in separate variables and then storing in array.

Answer (score 0):

You have used a colon instead of a semicolon.

Change

```
highscore.push(100):
```

to

```
highscore.push(100);
```

Comment: Colon changed to semicolon.
Still no content being pushed to the highscore array.